# Monolith to Microservice data migration

Tags: migration, microservices, database-migration, data-migration, system-design

We are doing monolith to microservices transformation.

Transformation strategy is to develop baseline functionality that could suffice functionality for few accounts and functionalities would be added incrementally to suffice different accounts.

I need to design database migration system from monolith to microservice(database per microservice) with minimal/no manual efforts to migrate each account.

- The main challenge is monolith data, it is scattered in different tables with different logic.

Example: 
for an account - cost details are in cost table 
for another account - it is in conf table.

- Basically each account may have different source table and column for some data.

I'm planning to keep transformation and loading as generic as possible because we are offloading all the data fetching logic to different layer.

Comment: There is no easy fix for this. Be careful, do the change incrementally.

Comment: Thanks @Jonas, yeah understand that, I'm looking for some kind of dynamic query building using defaults(baseline code) or with provided metadata so this can be easy go for similar accounts or accounts with minimal customizations.